# Unable to Have (-) Dash in DataView Filter C#

Tags: c#, dataview, rowfilter

I have a column in datatable where the columname is  "last-updated" and I am trying to use the column name with filter like below

```
dv.RowFilter = " (last-updated >= #" + Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerStart.Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "# And Date <= #" + Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerEnd.Text).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "# ) ";
```

When I try to build I am getting

> "Cannot find colum [last]".

I have tried to add single quote arrounding the column name but still not working.

Comment: did you tried with [last-updated] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `-` acts like an [arithmetic operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691371%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in your case and this `RowFilter` thinks that `last` and `updated` as a two different columns and you try to calculate their differences.

Just wrap them with `[]` as `[last-updated]` in it should be fine.